# HTTPS proxy server python

Tags: python, ssl, https, proxy, server

I have a problem with my ssl server (in Python).
I set the SSL proxy connection in my browser, and try to connect to my ssl server.

This is the server:

```
import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer
import ssl

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', 443), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, server_side=True, certfile='server.crt', keyfile='server.key', do_handshake_on_connect=False)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

This is the error:

```
SSLError: [SSL: HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST] https proxy request (_ssl.c:1750)
```

I try to connect to the server in the browser.
its work if I went to address "https://127.0.0.1:443".
But, if I use in the server to proxy, I get the error...

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is that the full error?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand how a proxy server for HTTPS works.

What you are doing is to create a plain HTTPS server. What you should do is to create a HTTP server which handles the CONNECT request and creates a tunnel to the requested target. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_tunneling